# DataAnnotation for Required property MVC4 on formats other than string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I know there are many questions asked similar to this such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305784/dataannotation-for-required-property), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253283/required-attribute-for-datetime-property) ,[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006146/unobtrusive-validation-attributes-rendered-for-nullable-datetime) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852574/mvc3-attribute-validation-question)

i have tried nullable and other options other than custom validators.

**ExceptionMessage:**

```
"Property 'Total_Amount' on type 'myproject.ViewModel.AccountDetails' 
is invalid. Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with
[DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the 
declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]."

ExceptionType

"System.InvalidOperationException"
```

**Definition in ViewModel:**

```
[DisplayName("Total Due")]
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
       public decimal Total_Amount { get; set; }
```

After all manipulations if i change the type of all the attributes to string then it works fine. I din't get the possible behavior of MVC for this. Also i don't wish to  edit global.asax or write a custom validator.

**I need the reason why this isn't working not the work around for it.Since many have faced the same issue there should be some concrete reason for it**

Comment: Why would you ever mark a non-nullable value type with the Required attribute? By it's very own definition, a value type can never be null :-) This attribute only makes sense for types that can be null. For example: `public decimal? Total_Amount { get; set; }`. In all other cases you are just wasting metadata. Such problems usually occur when people do not use view models.

Comment: I have used a view model. It doesn't work with decimal? also